# vlookup error handling, error 2042

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, vlookup

I'm trying to get a `Vlookup` working in VBA, and I have this code:

```
Dim Result As Variant

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Result = Application.VLookup(Template.Range("A" & i).Value2, EDM.Range("B:BP"), 5, False)
        If IsError(Result) Then
            Template.Range("E" & i).Value2 = ""
        Else
            Template.Range("E" & i).Value2 = Result
        End If
    Next i
```

For some reason every cell is coming up blank. If I manually type the formula in a cell with a match it works fine. I'm guessing it has something to do with the error handling, maybe? The goal is to look up the value in Template, column A against EDM column B and return EDM Column G.

Comment: your lookup is returning the 5th column starting from column B, i.e. column F, which is not column G as you wrote. maybe column F has blanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, it is related to your Error Handling, you need to trap the `VLookup` error a bit differently, by using `If IsError(Application.VLookup...)`.

**Note**: in your post you wrote you are looking to compare "against EDM column B", in your code you wrote `EDM.Range("B:BP")`, so which one is it?

Try the code below :

```
Dim Result As Variant

For i = 2 To lastrow
    If IsError(Application.VLookup(Template.Range("A" & i).Value2, EDM.Range("B:BP"), 6, False)) Then
        Template.Range("E" & i).Value2 = ""
    Else
        Result = Application.VLookup(Template.Range("A" & i).Value2, EDM.Range("B:BP"), 6, False)
        Template.Range("E" & i).Value2 = Result
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Why should it be different acting as OP's code? He's first storing the result of `Application.VLookup()` into a `Variant` variable (i.e. the return  type of that very method) and then check it with `IsError()`. Also, he's right in saying he's checking against EDM column B, since `VLookup()` checks the _first_ column of the passed range. While OP's wrong when saying he's returning column G since the fifth column after B is column F

Comment: @Swolerosis so which column do you want to return ? F or G?

Comment: I needed G. Once i changed it to 6, both versions of the code worked.

Comment: @Swolerosis ok, modified in my code as well. in case someone reads this post in the future :)